# How can I download information from bank accounts?

Tags: api, finance

There are a number of free finance tracking sites out there like mint.com, wesabe.com etc.. .

I've tried all of them and all seem to miss the mark in one way or another. I'm interested in creating my own website, or possibly just a stand alone windows program for tracking my finances in ASP.NET or C#.NET.

I'm assuming the answer is no, but is there any way that a personal developer can download transactions from financial websites like these? I know once you login to most financial sites you can download a CSV or Quicken file. Yet I really like how I can log-in to my Mint.com account and update all my accounts with one click.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Popular applications (like Quicken) and most major US banks support **[Open Financial Exchange (OFX)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Financial_Exchange)**. If a bank can connect to Quicken, it probably supports OFX (though not guaranteed).

Comment: Awesome thanks a lot. Exactly what I was looking for. Honestly I'm surprised something like this even exists with the way banks are.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt very many banks have public APIs for this. More likely than not, you will need to  send HTTPS requests to the various banking websites, and you will probably have to have custom code for each bank that you wish to support, tailored to the structure of their websites and their form elements.